# opencart 1.5.6.4 Add image in the middle of category list

Tags: opencart

I want to show an image or banner in the middle of product category list page. So if there are 10 products in the product category list then it will show 5 product, and then the image, and then the rest 5 product. 
Can anybody show me how to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open this file:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl
```

find `foreach` for products:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
```

create a variable as a counter before `foreach`:

then go to the end of `foreach` (line 99):

```
<?php } ?>
```

add following code before it:

```
<?php if($i == 5){ ?>
    <p>here is place for image</p>
<?php } $i++; ?>
```

Here is full code for `foreach` section:

```
<?php $i = 1; foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
<div>
  <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
  <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
  <div class="description"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></div>
  <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
  <div class="price">
    <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
    <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
    <br />
    <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
  <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="cart">
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />
  </div>
  <div class="wishlist"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a></div>
  <div class="compare"><a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></div>
</div>
<?php if($i == 5){ ?>
    <p>here is place for image</p>
<?php } $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Awesome dud. Thanks